# Can't establish connection to localhost when offline

Tags: android, serversocket, nanohttpd, localserversocket

I build a webserver on my android device by [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) or [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and connect to this server from itself. It run good when device is online. But I can't receive request when device isn't online. I was try connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` but nothing happen. Is there anyway to establish connection to `localhost` when device is offline?

Thanks

Comment: `and connect to this server from itself` ??? What do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry my english is not good. It's mean this http server run on my device and I send request from this device.

Comment: And who is sending the request? And how? And what do you use? NanoHttpd or a ServerSocket?

Comment: Scenario is show offline map tile on Mapbox. I add a RasterLayer on Mapbox and It will send request to a server for Map Tile, and I build a NanoHttpd server as a Tile Server and return Map Tile as image when Mapbox send request to it. But when tun-off wifi, the request isn't sent to NanoHttpd server

Comment: If the request is not send to NanoHttpd server then you cannot blame NanoHttpd server. You should blame the one who is not sending the request. So blame Mapbox if it is indead not requesting if wifi is off.

Comment: I use NanoHttpd a lot and wifi does not have to be switched on. And i did nothing to obtain this behaviour.

Comment: I've try send request by manual but NanoHttpd server doesn't receive this request.

Comment: `I've try send request by manual` ??? What would that be?

Comment: I hard code to send request

Comment: Hard code? Then please show your code! And why dont you try with a browser on your device?

Comment: Humm, It doesn't receive request from browser. Thanks

Comment: `It run good when device is online.` It is pretty unclear to me what you mean with online. Anyhow: wifi does not have to be switched on.

Answer (score 1):

Try constructing your server using [NanoHTTPD(String host, int port)](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/nanohttpd/protocols/http/NanoHTTPD.java#L365) constructor and specify either `127.0.0.1` (for localhost loopback interface) or `0.0.0.0` (for all interfaces). This way you will be able to connect to your server regardless of device's connectivity.

```
public class MyHttpd extends NanoHTTPD {
  public MyHttpd(){
    super('0.0.0.0', 8080);
    // ....
  }

  // ....
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I try `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` but method [serve()][1] wan't called

[1]: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/nanohttpd/protocols/http/NanoHTTPD.java#L549

Comment: can you please add the HTTP server snippet in the OP?